# Trying to disable users in AD who are not in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I've been trying to find analogs to this in the forums, but it's the logic that's tying me up - putting it all together.

I have an AD and I have a CSV of users that should be in a particular OU. I want to compare the users in the OU to the CSV, and users NOT in the CSV, I want to disable them and move them to a different OU.

I'm new to Powershell and having a bit of a rough time with this. What's getting me is the comparison and IF-Then logic...I just can't get the syntax right. I've tried a few options...this is what I have right now

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$path     = "f:\aDMGMT\"
$logpath = "f:\admgmt\logs\diable_ad_users.log"
$userfile  = $path + "\files\ad_currentemployees.csv"
$location = "OU=Faculty,OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
$disabledou = "OU=disabledemployees,OU=Disabled,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
$AD_users =  Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Faculty,OU=People,DC=mydomain,DC=com" | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$sams = $userfile | Select-Object -ExpandProperty NameUnique #the
Compare-Object $AD_users $sams | Out-File $logpath
```

But the tags available are things like includeequal and excludedifferent...but not includedifferent...and how would I do it for only one side?

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-thought my logic and came up with this. It works perfectly.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop
$path       = "f:\aDMGMT\"
$date       = Get-Date
$logdate    = Get-Date -UFormat "%y%m%d"
$log        = $path+"\logs\diable_ad_users_"+$logdate+".log"
$userfile   = $path + "\files\ad_currentemployees.csv"
$location   = "OU=employees,OU=People,DC=myorg,DC=com"
$disabledou = "OU=disabledemployees,OU=Disabled,DC=myorg,DC=com"
$AD_users   =  Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=employees,OU=People,DC=myorg,DC=com" | select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$sams       = Import-csv $userfile | select nameunique

ForEach ($user in $AD_users)
{
$exists = $sams.nameunique -contains $user # clean output for array w/ header vs. array without header demands .namunique
If(!$exists)
{
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user | Move-ADObject -targetpath $disabledou
    Disable-ADAccount -Identity $user
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is pipe the results into a `where` clause using the `SideIndicator` to filter on.

```
Compare-Object $AD_users $sams | 
    Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | 
    Select-Object -expandproperty inputobject
```

Using the direction that you need, either `"<="` or `"=>"`, you would then pipe into a `Select-Object` to restore the input object that you were filtering on. That last part would be more important if your object was multidimensional.

I am going to try this with real data as this has only breifly tested but should work.

Comment: I KNEW those arrows in my log file would be helpful for something, but I was futzing with them via ImportCSV, instead of using Where-Object - I feel silly I didn't come across this. I will try this in a little bit and let you know how it goes!

Comment: ok, I tried this and I'm getting no dice when selecting for things on the AD side. I get an error message when substituting "SAMAccountName" where you have the placeholder of inputobject. Any insight?

Comment: @JenDavenport dont use a substitute. inputobject is the actual property returned by `compare-object`